# python qwidget closeEvent doesn't call

Tags: python, events, pyqt4

I created form using designer.
So, I have 3 files:

**1. Form.py:** - autocreated from designer

`..... bla-bla-bla ......
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(1920, 1000)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1000))
..... bla-bla-bla ......`

**2. FormProc.py:**  - manual created for processing

```
from Form import *

class FormProc(Ui_Form):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Ui_Form.setupUi(self, Form)
  ..... bla-bla-bla ......
```

**3. Main.py:**  - main file

```
import sys
from FormProc import *

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
    mw=FormProc()
    mw.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I need to catch closeEvent, but I can't. Defining of closeEvent function in FormProc.py does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the class definition in **Form.py**, you'll see that it's just a simple namespace that inherits from `object`. The `setupUi` method creates all the widgets specified in Qt Deisgner and makes them attributes of this namespace. The only excetion to this is the top-level widget, which must be passed in to `setupUi` as the `Form` argument.

So the `FormProc` class you created in **FormProc.py** is currently completely redundant. To make it useful, you need to make it a subclass of the *top-level widget*, and then add the ui to that. There are several ways to do this. Here's one way:

FormProc.py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from Form import Ui_Form

class FormProc(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormProc, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('close event')
```

Main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from FormProc import FormProc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    MainWindow = FormProc()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For some other examples, see [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) in the PyQt4 docs.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! But, unfortunately, I should refactor all code: from self.pushbutton to self.ui.pushbutton.

Comment: @IliyaFiks. Refactoring is not necessary, because you can use the multiple inheritance approach. See the third example from the link in my answer.